# ElasticSearch: Full Text Search with query_string having multi fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am doing `full text search` with **ElasticSearch**. I am using [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query). I am doing search with [Multi Field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field) feature.

My query looks like below:

```
 {
    "query": {
         "query_string": {
            "fields": [
                "field1^5",
                "field2^5",
                "field3^1",
                "field4^1",
                ...................
                ...................
            ],
            "query": "....",
            "default_operator": "OR",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        }
    }
 }
```

I have more than `30 fields` in my collection. For my requirement, I need to ensure that `fieldA`, `fieldB` need to be searched first. Hence these fields will have `higher priority`. Other fields all have `low and equal priority`.

So, is there some way where I don't have to `specify all the field names in the query`. I only want to specify those fields that have higher priority i.e `fieldA` , `fieldB`. But, the searching should be performed on all fields based on priority order.

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Didn't understand your question. @oblivion

Comment: @DivyeshGausvami In a nutshell, I want to perform full text search on multiple fields. Among those fields, two of them have very high priority and they need to be matched first. So, in the query, I want to specify those 2 fields only by giving them higher boost value.If those 2 fields do not match the query, then only other fields need to be matched. So here, do I always need to specify all the fields in the query ? Is there some way where I dont have to list all the low priority fields in the query ?

Comment: `{
   "query":{
      "multi_match" : {
         "query": "searching string",
         "fields": [ "field1", "field2",... ,"fieldN"]
      }
   }
}`
This might be helpful to you? am i right ?

Comment: Yes, but that is the solution that I already have.With this approach, I need to put all `30 fields` in my query. But only fields: `"fieldA"` and `"fieldB"` are of higher priority. So, I only want to keep `"field1"` and `"field2"` in the query. So, I am looking for a way if this is possible.

Comment: @oblivion Did you try `_all` field? Where you can have all low priority fields included in `_all` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this . Tested in my system ,its working for me :-

```
 {
    "query": {
         "query_string": {
            "fields": [
                "field1^5",
                "field2^5",
                "_all",
            ],
            "query": "....",
            "default_operator": "OR",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot !! One more thing I want to ask is that do I need to assign a priority to `_all` as well, such as :  `"_all^1"` ?

Comment: No need . According to elastic search doc - "boost -

Sets the boost value of the query. Defaults to 1.0."  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: can i do the same with NEST , as i have a similar issue using the QueryString with multiple fields